# RecipientCorrection error: Email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows

Tags: email, docusignapi

I am using SOAP to request a CorrectAndResendEnvelope from the DocuSignAPI;  Getting the error message "The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows" from DocuSign.  The request includes an RecipientCorrection object with the exact email address, user name and routing number returned by DocuSignAPI using RequestStatus of the envelope for the recipient whose name needs to change.

This error message is not included in the API documentation under Exceptions thrown by the API.  Anyone else seen this?

Comment: How many recipients in total are part of the envelope, do they have increasing routing orders, which one are you trying to change, and at what's the status of the whole envelope? (I.e. is it draft status, etc.)

Comment: So far in my tests the CorrectAndResendEnvelope() call is working fine for me...

Comment: Three recipients total; I am correcting only one at a time.
None of the recipients have signed, so their statuses are Sent.
Routing numbers are all 1.
Envelope status is Sent (In Process shown in console).
First test:  second recipient who is captive (embedded), hence I am populating ClientUserId in CorrectedCaptiveInfo.  (Correcting a captive recipient through the console removes the ClientUserId, making it unfindable by subsequent calls.)
Second test:  first recipient who is remote.

Comment: Ergin, for the remote call, I am populating PreviousEmail, PreviousUserName, PreviousRoutingOrder and CorrectedUserName.  Should I be populating PreviousSignerName or any Corrected properties that are not changing?

Answer (score 1):

In the end Support found the issue after I submitted the SOAP messages for the request and response.  A requirement, which is not documented, is you are required to apply the <CorrectedEmail>  even if you are not actually correcting the email address.  It may also follow that if you're changing the email, you may be required to apply the <CorrectedUserName> as well.

Support also confirmed that the <SignerName> is used only when utilizing In-Person signing for the recipient.  In this latter case, the <...UserName> would be the person who owns the DocuSign membership and the <...SignerName> would be the person actually signing the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only correct/modify recipients when:

```
1)  They have not signed yet
2)  It is NOT their turn in the routingOrder yet.
```

Based on your comments it looks like you are creating an envelope with 3 recipients who all have `routingOrder = 1` and sending the envelope but not signing anything yet.  This means that you should not be able to correct any of these recipients, since they are all routingOrder = 1 and the current routingOrder of the envelope is 1.

The reason for #2 is that if it's currently a recipient's routingOrder it's possible they might sign at any instant, so if you are trying to do a recipient correction at the same time as they sign in between the time your request is sent off then there would be a conflict.

To get around this you'll have to either attempt to correct the recipients BEFORE you send the envelope, or give the recipients different routing orders (i.e. 1, 2, 2 or 1, 2, 3, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The routing order did not make a difference...and as an in-session signer, they would never be possible to "sign at any instant", only when our application allows them to, which would be after the recipient change.